# Is 知{し}らんけど a phrase in every dialect or just kansai?

Tags: dialects

I was looking on a forum of some sorts and I saw people use 知{し}らんけど. After I looked it up, some of the results said it was from the kansai dialect. Is this common throughout or just in kansai?

Comment: 「知らんけど」って関西ではめっちゃよう使いますね。よそは知らんけど。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The けど is just casual for けれども and exists throughout the whole country.

The negative 〜ん is a contraction of the mostly archaic negation 〜ぬ. In Kansai it is used, although 〜へん might be more typical there. It is also the negative ending of choice throughout the whole of Kyushu. Generally speaking, you can say that it occurs in the Western parts of Japan.

Here is a great table for comparing characteristics of different dialects in Japan: https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E8%AA%9E%E3%81%AE%E6%96%B9%E8%A8%80%E3%81%AE%E6%AF%94%E8%BC%83%E8%A1%A8#.E4.B9.9D.E5.B7.9E.EF.BC.88.E8.A5.BF.E6.B5.B7.E9.81.93.EF.BC.89

Search for 否定｛ひてい｝ = negation in the table, to see some different types.

The particular combination of 知らんけど has a special usage in the Kansai region, being a form of multi-use ending to soften what you are saying. I have not encountered this usage in other parts of Japan where the negative 〜ん is used (except for when you really mean "I don't know, but" without any special nuance added to it). As my dialect is not Kansai, I will let someone else explain the details of the full phrase.